# disable devise user registration and move that functionality to an admin method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, subdomain

I would like to disable user registration for devise and move the creation of new users to an admin method under an admin namespace.

How could this be accomplished? I have searched and think I have to overrule the devise controllers disabling the custom user registration.

But how to make a new user based on a form under an admin namespace? Anyone done such a thing before and could share some pointers on how to get it done? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the devise Wiki, quite a common question (think this is what you are looking for)

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in